# Widgets in React.js

Tags: reactjs

How can I use this widget in my React project, please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var para_birimleri="USD-EUR-GBP";
var arka_plan="FFFFFF";
var cerceve="333333";
var kutucuk="FFFFFF";
var piyasa_baslik="FFFFFF";
var tur_baslik="999999";
var fiyat_baslik="CC3300";
var kutu_kose="oval";
var genislik="120";
var bankalar="acik";
var paylasim="kapali";
</script>
<div style="width:120px;font-size:12px;text-align:right;"><a name="piyasadoviz" target="_blank"  href="http://altin.piyasadoviz.com/fiyat">altın hakkında</a></div><script type="text/javascript" charset="iso-8859-9" src="http://eklenti.piyasadoviz.com/doviz.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create component with iframe

so you will create simple widget.html file

inside your component you will use `<iframe src="/widget.html?para_birimleri=EUR-GBP"`

and use get param inside html